# How can I display images and different variables depends on some conditions in this code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, bufferedreader

I am learning java and i am pretty new for it. I am trying to create a static profile window using swing. Also, the avatar picture should change depending on user and user information should be read from a text file. This code doesnt give a error but its because of `avatarPath`. I think the program thinks its non-static.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 *
 * @author B_Ali
 */
public class ProfilePanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static String avatarPath;
    public static int x;  
    public static class UsersInfo{
    public int userID;    
    public String userName;
    public String userSurname;
    public String userGender;

UsersInfo(String name, String surname, String gender){         
        userID = x;
        userName = name;
        userSurname = surname;
        userGender = gender;
}
}
static UsersInfo permitedUser[];
public static void InfoReader()throws IOException{
       @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
       BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\B_Ali\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication20\\UserInformation.txt"));
        String s, s2 = new String();
        while((s = in.readLine())!= null)
            s2 += s + "\n";
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")

                String[] s1 = new String[100];
        s1 = s2.split("\\s+");
        in.close();
        permitedUser[0] = new UsersInfo( s1[0] , s1[1], s1[2] );
        permitedUser[1] = new UsersInfo ( s1[3], s1[4], s1[5] );
        permitedUser[2] = new UsersInfo ( s1[6], s1[7], s1[8] );

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {

    }
}
public static void ProfilePanel() {
    initComponents();
}
public static String AvatarPic(){

    if( x == 0 ){
    avatarPath = "\"/Users/hei_cosplay_darker_than_black_by_seras0victoria.jpg\"";
    }
    else if( x == 1 ){
    avatarPath = "\"/Users/lyralei_the_windrunner_by_trungth-d5zhmc1.jpg\"";    
    }
    else if( x == 2 ){
    avatarPath = "\"/Users/shingeki_no_kyojin_by_asuka10-d6k762k.jpg\""; 
    }
    return avatarPath;}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    jFrame2 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
    jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
    jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame2.getContentPane());
    jFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame2Layout);
    jFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Avatar", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(ProfilePanel.AvatarPic())));
    jLabel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255), 2, true));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

    jScrollPane2.setName(""); // NOI18N

    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    try {
        ProfilePanel.InfoReader();      // TODO add your handling code here:
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    jTextArea1.setText("Name: " +permitedUser[x].userName+ "\r\nSurname :"+permitedUser[x].userSurname+"\r\nGender :"+permitedUser[x].userGender);
    jTextArea1.setDragEnabled(true);
    jTextArea1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(2147483647, 120));
    jTextArea1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(92, 120));
    jTextArea1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(164, 120));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, 0)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, 0))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(50, 50, 50))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(120, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = in.nextInt();

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ProfilePanel().setVisible(true);
        }
    });


}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame2;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
public javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
public javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Edit: I changed code a bit and it gives error.
Edit2: what I am trying to do is creating users and their profiles. Profile will contain avatar image and 3 variable which are name, surname and gender. I want to display them with respect to users.

I am living problems with this codes;

```
static void AvatarPic(){ 
    if( x == 0 ){
    avatarPath = "\"/Users/hei_cosplay_darker_than_black_by_seras0victoria.jpg\"";
    }
    else if( x == 1 ){
    avatarPath = "\"/Users/lyralei_the_windrunner_by_trungth-d5zhmc1.jpg\"";    
    }
    else if( x == 2 ){
    avatarPath = "\"/Users/shingeki_no_kyojin_by_asuka10-d6k762k.jpg\""; 
    }
    }
```

and

```
ProfilePanel.AvatarPic();
jLabel1.setIcon(new
javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(ProfilePanel.avatarPath)));
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? Hard to understand what you're actually asking. But to me it looks like you're getting your path from x but you never actually set x to anything, you just declare it and use the default value in your program.

Comment: Do you even get an error trace?

Comment: Your path is incorrect. It does not need the escaped quotes. And if you are using an absolute path (which I would not recommend), you can simply pass the path to the `ImageIcon` constructor without having to call `getClass().getResource()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.

1. The `initComponents()` is not a static function .I guess in your static conversion you just replaced every function with public static .And the below is a constructor [I'm sure because it is a `Netbeans` generated one] and you have modified it also.No need to do that

   ```
    public static void ProfilePanel() {
      initComponents();
     }
   ```

   You can change it back to the way it was

   ```
   public ProfilePanel() {
     initComponents();
    }
   ```
2. You'll get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at

   ```
   jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(ProfilePanel.AvatarPic())));
   ```

   because if you are using [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) you just have to specify the filename relative to the package.If you'll be loading from other location,then you have to change it [like](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String))

   ```
   jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(ProfilePanel.AvatarPic()));//file location
   ```

   Also you have to give the absolute path

   ```
   avatarPath = "D://hei_cosplay_darker_than_black_by_seras0victoria.jpg";
   ```
3. You'll again get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at

   ```
   permitedUser[0] = new UsersInfo(s1[0], s1[1], s1[2]);
   ```

   because you haven't initialized the `permitedUser` anywhere.So you have to do it like

   ```
   static UsersInfo permitedUser[]=new UsersInfo[3];
   ```

After making those changes and if you run it with 0 then BK201[Code Name Hei] will be on your screen

**And Your Edited FullCode**[Make change to ImageLocations]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author B_Ali
 */
public class ProfilePanel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static String avatarPath;
public static int x;

public static class UsersInfo {

    public int userID;
    public String userName;
    public String userSurname;
    public String userGender;

    UsersInfo(String name, String surname, String gender) {
        userID = x;
        userName = name;
        userSurname = surname;
        userGender = gender;
    }
}
static UsersInfo permitedUser[] = new UsersInfo[3];//change 3

public static void InfoReader() throws IOException {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\B_Ali\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication20\\UserInformation.txt"));
        String s, s2 = new String();
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            s2 += s + "\n";
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")

        String[] s1 = new String[100];
        s1 = s2.split("\\s+");
        in.close();
        permitedUser[0] = new UsersInfo(s1[0], s1[1], s1[2]);
        permitedUser[1] = new UsersInfo(s1[3], s1[4], s1[5]);
        permitedUser[2] = new UsersInfo(s1[6], s1[7], s1[8]);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {

    }
}
//Change 1
public ProfilePanel() {
    initComponents();
}

public static String AvatarPic() {
//change 2
    if (x == 0) {
        avatarPath = "D://hei_cosplay_darker_than_black_by_seras0victoria.jpg";
    } else if (x == 1) {
        avatarPath = "D://lyralei_the_windrunner_by_trungth-d5zhmc1.jpg";
    } else if (x == 2) {
        avatarPath = "D://shingeki_no_kyojin_by_asuka10-d6k762k.jpg";
    }
    return avatarPath;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

    jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    jFrame2 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
    jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
    jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame2.getContentPane());
    jFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame2Layout);
    jFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Avatar", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

   //Change 2
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(ProfilePanel.AvatarPic()));
    jLabel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255), 2, true));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Information", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

    jScrollPane2.setName(""); // NOI18N

    jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    try {
        ProfilePanel.InfoReader();      // TODO add your handling code here:
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    jTextArea1.setText("Name: " + permitedUser[x].userName + "\r\nSurname :" + permitedUser[x].userSurname + "\r\nGender :" + permitedUser[x].userGender);
    jTextArea1.setDragEnabled(true);
    jTextArea1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(2147483647, 120));
    jTextArea1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(92, 120));
    jTextArea1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(164, 120));
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, 0))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(50, 50, 50))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap(120, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
/* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = in.nextInt();

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ProfilePanel().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify   

private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame2;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
public javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
public javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```